# Позиционирование элементов в HTML

Tags: html, css

Eсть такая задача:
На моем сайте с `десктоп` версией есть блоки со списками:

```html
<div class="let-column" style="width: 49%; float: left">
  <ul>
    <li>Таб_1</li>
    <li>Таб_2</li>
    <li>Таб_3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="right-column" style="width: 49%; float: left">
  <ul>
    <li>Тело_1</li>
    <li>Тело_2</li>
    <li>Тело_3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Что дает мне некую природу `табов` в 2 колонки.

Требуется на мобильной версии сайта сделать так, чтобы те же блоки располагались вот так:

```html
<div class="let-column" style="width: 49%; float: left">
  <ul>
    <li>Таб_1</li>
    <li>Тело_1</li>
    <li>Таб_2</li>
    <li>Тело_2</li>
    <li>Таб_3</li>
    <li>Тело_3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="right-column" style="width: 49%; float: left; display: none">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вместо перемещение елементов, можно добавить во второй список елеметы первого и скрывать/показывать их с помощью `@media`

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tabs__nav,
.tabs__content {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  list-style: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .tabs__mobile-item {
    display: none; 
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .tabs__nav {
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
      <ul class="tabs__nav">
        <li class="tabs__nav-item">Tab 1</li>
        <li class="tabs__nav-item">Tab 2</li>
        <li class="tabs__nav-item">Tab 3</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="tabs__content">
        <li class="tabs__nav-item tabs__mobile-item">Tab 1</li>
        <li class="tabs__content-item">Content 1</li>
   
        <li class="tabs__nav-item tabs__mobile-item">Tab 2</li>
        <li class="tabs__content-item">Content 2</li>

        <li class="tabs__nav-item tabs__mobile-item">Tab 3</li>
        <li class="tabs__content-item">Content 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Нет, ксерить элементы НЕЛЬЗЯ. Суть именно в том, чтобы проделать все это с одними и теми же элементами. Думаю, всетаки на JS сделаю аппендами

Comment: @berTalino, Так категорично. Тогда учтите, что вам нужно еще будет проверять размер экрана и исходя из него перемещать елементы.

Comment: Нкда .. так и сделаю isTouch пропишу

Comment: Не нужен тут ни какой `JS`, просто `HTML` грамотно  надо сверстать, как и почти показал тебе в ответе @E_K

Comment: Я не знаю каким должен быть конечный результат, но в отображение на планшете как пример с 1024px и на смартфоне 320px есть разница и isTouch как по мне не вариант, да и JS для такой задачи.

Comment: Да, понятно, но савойствами CSS как ни пляши неканает

Answer (score 1):

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tabs__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .tabs__nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabs__nav">
    <li class="tabs__nav-item">Tab 1</li>
    <li class="tabs__content-item">Content 1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tabs__nav">
    <li class="tabs__nav-item">Tab 2</li>
    <li class="tabs__content-item">Content 2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tabs__nav">
    <li class="tabs__nav-item">Tab 3</li>
    <li class="tabs__content-item">Content 3</li>
  </ul>
```